# I left a question in the chat I'd like you to see

Tags: discussion

Well, I don't know whether Meta is appropriate to point users like this, but I left a question in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2185/poker) I'd like an opinion about.

So what I'd like here in meta to ask you:

- Could you all review this question in the chat (regarding suddenly closing a tournament) and give me an opinion? (I mean: in the same chat)
- Is that question appropriate / on-topic to be posted as a regular question in the main poker.se site?

Comment: It would be better if you posted the question here rather than have to look it up in chat.

Comment: You're right. Finally I posted the question in the main QA.
I think I'm editing this question to add the chat's content.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's a good question and it fits very well with the QA format of the Poker.SE site.

You can post it with no worries.